# How can i update context value with the state value

Tags: reactjs, use-state, use-context

I can receive the correct object, but i can't update the context value with the updated object with the state value

In the:

```
const Context = createContext({
  theme: dark,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});
```

I want to make the theme: dark, become, theme: defaultTheme, with a dynamic value modified by useState

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

import light from '../themes/light';
import dark from '../themes/dark';

const Context = createContext({
  theme: dark,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});

export default Context;

export function ThemeContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [defaultTheme, setDefaultTheme] = useState(dark);

  function toggleTheme() {
    setDefaultTheme(defaultTheme === dark ? light : dark);
  }
  
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
    {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an **undefined** value to the context provider. (*`theme` is undefined inside the `ThemeContextProvider` component*). You need to pass the `defaultTheme` instead.

```
<Context.Provider value={{ theme: defaultTheme, toggleTheme }}>
    {children}
</Context.Provider>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sguq3)